# Как запустить эмулятор устройства в IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: j2me, java, intellij-idea

Добрый День!
Вот установил эту прогу, как альтернативу NetBeans, так как там приходится долго ждать, пока эмулятор запустится. Конечно, там что-то высвечивалось в подсказках, "чтобы сэкономить время, оставляйте запущенным эмулятор и разворачивайте нужные проекты", но я не понял как это сделать. А IntelliJ IDEA вроде компилирует быстро и сам эмулятор говорят быстрее грузиться, но я не могу понять, какие настройки задать, чтоб он отобразился...

Вот, например, мой Main:

```
    import javax.microedition.lcdui.
    import javax.microedition.;
    import javax.microedition.midlet.MIDlet; 
    import java.awt.*;

public class Main extends MIDlet{
    protected void destroyApp(boolean b) throws MIDletStateChangeException {
        //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
       // Display.getDisplay(this);
        Frame f = new Frame("Hello World!");

        f.show();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    protected void pauseApp() {
        //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.

    }

    protected void startApp() throws MIDletStateChangeException {
        //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.

    }
}
```

Он компилится, но эмулятор не появляется. Посоветуйте, что делать?

Comment: Как эмулятор, будучи сторонней программой, может быстрее грузиться?!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Аттачим JDK - через меню Project Structure->JDKs->Add new JDK и указываем на каталог где лежит заранее скачанная J2ME платформа
2. Далее Project->Run - в меню Device выбираем эмулятор, указываем на JAD/JAR/Midlet и проч. которые являются точкой входа
3. Жмем кнопку Run, запустится (довольно долго) собственно эмулятор

*P.S. На фига вам J2ME? Технология умирающая. Все приличные девелоперы ушли оттуда уж как года 3-4 назад.*

Comment: Спасибо,Barmaley!)
Я Android разработчик, но на собеседовании дали ТЗ, написать на Java тэтрис с использованием J2ME, вот и мучаю мозг как в этом всём разобраться.

Comment: @Kerins_Sataier вот так вот наверно и выходят программы для J2ME до сих пор, во время собеседований. Но вообще я удивлен такому заданию